# Why is "...and others" wrong in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Somebody asked me about this sentence:

> My business is closed on Thanksgiving, Christmas, and others.

I know that it should be *"...and other holidays"*, but I'm struggling to explain **why**.

Is this sentence grammatically incorrect? If so, is there a specific rule that's being violated? Or is it grammatically correct but [semantically nonsensical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically it's okay because you could say, e.g.

I spoke to John, Mary and others.

As far as I am aware 'others' when used as a pronoun, conventionally only ever refers to people. I don't think it would apply to family pets - maybe not even young children. Thus I would say it is an idiomatic usage.

Note: Please refer to remarks in the comments below this question for further insights.

Comment: @KannE - Could you give examples?

Comment: "She left us six pears; this one is riper than the **others**". Note that "others" is a common noun, not a pronoun.

Comment: @BillJ - Good point. I've amended my answer. Could you check I'm correct now. Thanks

Comment: @KannE - Ah yes, that makes sense. I've made a note in my answer about these comments.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific example “others” is not grammatically correct. It needs “holidays” in there somewhere.

“... other holidays.” would be fine. So would “... most holidays: Thanksgiving, Christmas, and others.”

Notable exceptions to this rule would be headlines and signs, which routinely break normal grammatical rules in the interest of brevity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I mentioned in my question, I know that it needs "holidays" in there somewhere- but **why** is it wrong? Is there a specific grammar rule that's being violated?

Comment: KannE had an excellent comment previously about antecedents. I was merely providing a couple of relevant options to illustrate. (I suppose I should have posted a comment after his/hers rather than an answer but as a newbie I wasn’t allowed to comment at that point.). I appreciate your reference to semantic nonsense. But your original example sentence is reasonably clear, just missing an important element. As subsets of the implied word “holidays”, “Christmas” and “Thanksgiving” lead us in the right direction to figure the sentence out, but stop short of providing us with a true antecedent.